# Class Design utilising numpy arrays

Tags: python, class, numpy

I have a class which accepts three arguments:

```
class Spheroid(object):
def __init__(self, shortaxis, longaxis, height):
    self.shortax = shortaxis
    self.longax  = longaxis
    self.h       = height
    self.alpha   = longaxis/shortaxis
```

This is fine, but sometimes I like to do something like:

```
heights = np.linspace(0,1,100)

a = Spheroid(1.0,2.0,heights)

a.h
```

which gives me an array of the heights.

The longaxis and shortaxis are input parameters which I measure, but sometimes I'd like to do something like

```
class Spheroid(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha, height):
         self.alpha = alpha
         self.h     = height

alphas = np.linspace(0,3,30)

b = Spheroids(alphas, 0.5)

b.alpha
```

but I want to keep the longax and shortax as input parameters so I don't have to calculate alpha by hand.

Any ideas on how I can design this class to do what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, which makes telling you how to design the class hard. Either of your designs could work, I think. There's no way to compute `shortax` and `longax` from `alpha` though, so the first may be more useful if you need all three values.

Comment: Well you can compute shortax and longax from alpha, there are just an infinite number of possible choices of shortax and longax, which is the problem :(